# Bootstrap navbar not moving down while scrolling

Tags: css, navbar, nav

I've been looking for answers on here and several other sites on this.  There have been some, but I can't seem to get it to work still.  I have the following navbar:

```
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="#About">About me</a>
  <a href="#Education">Education</a>
  <a href="#Portfolio">Portfolio</a>
  <a href="#Contact">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

I've tried it with and without a div container on the inside of the nav tags.

Here's the corresponding CSS:

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  lef: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 35px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 100;
}
```

I've also tried it without z-index: 100;
If anyone knows what I'm missing, or if I need something else to add, I'd be interested in seeing what it is and where I can read up on it so I get it.

Thanks :)

Comment: what exactly do you mean by "not moving down" and what do you want? Should the navbar stay fixed on top of the window while the content scrolls under it or should it scroll away with the content?

Comment: Alright.  For clarification, then.  When I scroll down, the navbar at the top of the page disappears up above the screen.  I want it to stay on the top of the screen no matter where I'm scrolling down to

Comment: hmm - this is what "fixed" is suppposed to do. can you post some more code (html of the page, more css)?

Comment: I sure can.  Here it is back with the fixed attribute.
http://codepen.io/Jspadgett82/pen/KzgvYV/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a CSS rule for calss `.navbar` in there with `position: relative`. This overrides the fixed setting for `nav`

Add `!important` to your position:fixed setting for `nav`:

```
nav {
  text-align: center;
  position: fixed !important;
```

etc.

This should fix it.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZWBwEW

Comment: Actually... the funny thing is, I didn't.  Not in the codepen link I gave.  Either that or I fixed it after the fact, cause it was on fixed in the nav css thing.  I might have edited it as I was trying to figure out based on what people were telling me here!  Either way, once the relative was gone, it still didn't work.  Your !important made it automagically work, however, so tyvm!

Comment: the .navbar rule for relative position seems to come from bootstrap itself, I suppose. I found it using the browser's developer tools.

Comment: I legitimately was doing things as I was trying to figure this out.  I also didn't know that that worked that way.  Suppose I need to start figuring out what kinds of other things default to, to save myself these kinds of headaches in the future!  Hah!  Thanks again!

Comment: alternatively you could also set up a rule for the `.navbar` class containing `position: fixed`, which would override the "built-in" bootstrap setting for the `.navbar` class.

Comment: Good call on that one too.  That will also be remembered in case I don't remember to use !important hahah!

Comment: I did now.  I literally joined this place either the day of or the day before I even asked anything.  Already forgot.  Didn't know how, but I got it now!

Answer (score 0):

You've got position:fixed. And a typo "lef"

Comment: As above, I changed the position attribute, but the typo fix on top of that didn't work for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone here helped me out, because I did have a typo, and I did have what I was trying to do correct in the end.

Thanks in particular to Johannes, I realized that if you're trying to do this like me, and using Bootstrap, make sure you put !important after the position: fixed; in your css, as it overrides Bootstraps default properties in that regard, leaving you unable to keep the navbar on your screen while scrolling down!

Answer (score 0):

## Don't forget width should be 100%

nav {

```
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed !important;
 width: 100%;
```

}